# Can I add a controller directly to a module with chaining?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following:

```
var app = angular
    .module('app', ['admin', 'home', 'questions', 'ui.compat', 'ngResource', 'LocalStorageModule'])
    .config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) { 
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }])
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
        // $state.transitionTo('home.overview');
        $state.transitionTo('home', { contentTitle: 'overview' })
    }]);
```

What I would like to do is to add a controller to the 'app' module. Is it possible to do this with 
chaining and if so how should I do this?

Comment: Lazy lazy lazy question. Why didn't you just try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('app', ['admin', 'home', 'questions', 'ui.compat', 
'ngResource', 'LocalStorageModule']).controller('Ctrl', 
['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

Comment: Can I also chain this so that it follows right after the .run ?

Comment: Yes you can. Should not be a problem.